# AWS step function - Calls REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to call the REST API from AWS step function?. I want to call the REST APIs that is available in Kubernetes container and thrid party API.

Answer (score 6):

You would have to call your REST API from a Lambda function: a task state with a lambda function specified as a resource.

See [Task - Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html#amazon-states-language-task-state-lambda).

Comment: Are you saying we can call only AWS services from step function?

Comment: Exactly, you can see the list of supported services here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html. If you want to call a REST API you will have to implement your own logic using a Lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago, AWS has introduced this option to call HTTP API via AWS API Gateway, "[Call API Gateway with Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html)". It can be helpful if you already expose your API via AWS API Gateway, otherwise, using AWS Lambda function to wrap the HTTP call, may be simpler and probably good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible natively, without Lambda:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-third-party-apis.html